# How to change the text of a div element using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom

In the following HTML:

```
<div class="stylesSelectDropdown__dropdown-label-single____d17A">**Client_1_name**</div>
```

Instead of `Client_1_name` I want to change it to `Client_2_name` using python selenium. Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Please be more clear with your question. Do you want to change the value of an div input?

Answer (score 1):

To change the *`innerText`* of the `<div>` element

```
<div class="stylesSelectDropdown__dropdown-label-single____d17A">Client_1_name</div>
```

from *`Client_1_name`* to *`Client_2_name`* you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using *innerText*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Client_1_name']")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'Client_2_name'", element)
  ```
- Using *`setAttribute()`*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Client_1_name']")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('innerHTML','Client_2_name')", element)
  ```